# How to interact with blockchain without need of refreshing page in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, blockchain, smartcontracts, metamask

Hello I am currently working on a blockchain app . The problem is when I confirm the transaction with metamask notification, I need to refresh the page to see the changes. Is there is any way to avoid refreshing pages ?

Comment: Did you try anything already and face issues?

Comment: Yes I tried to use useEffect hook from react whenever I call smart contract function from frontend but it did not work. I guess we cannot use function call as a dependency for useEffect to trigger the update.